# Titles are pushing content to the next page in css print styles

Tags: css, printing, printing-web-page

I'm trying to finish a print stylesheet for a site. It's not my first time working on print stylesheets, though this time I'm stuck with a problem I cannot solve. I need to be able to print a list of results after a search and I can do that. The only problem is that the title of the search results keeps pushing the content to the next page. This results into a page with only a title and it's subtitle, then the content prints on the next page, and at the end I'm always left with one or more blank pages.

How can I get the content to print after the title on the same page?

You can see how the page behaves with the print styles using the Developper Toolbar and typing: 
**media emulate print**,
then press enter. This will show the page with the print styles in the browser and will allow you to use the inspector to check those styles.

Here is the link to the page I'm trying to print:
http://sebthiroux.com/cridon-paris/site-bases/recherche-globale-resultats.html#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was, it was mainly that I was too tired to see what I wrote in my css print stylesheet. I had the following style that forced the ul to start on the next page : 
`ul { page-break-inside: avoid; }`

That's all it was.